# How impl &dyn trait bounds for generics?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to create a  `Vec<T>` where `T` is bound to a trait called HTML:

```rust
pub trait HTML {
    fn to_email_body(&self) -> String;
}
```

Now I want to have a struct with:

```rust
impl Body {
pub fn new(from: String, to: Vec<String>, components: Vec<C>) -> Self 
    where C: HTML 
    {
        Self {
            from,
            to,
            components,
        }
    }
}
```

So I can pass `components` with a generic type `T` to the `new` constructor.

However, I have to create a `Vec<&dyn HTML>` so Rust can size it during compile time:

```rust
let mut components: Vec<&dyn HTML> = Vec::new();
components.push(&dashboard);
```

How would a trait impl look like for this? So far I have

```rust
impl HTML for Dashboard {
    fn to_email_body(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}", self)
    }
}
```

And now I am getting the following error:

```
the trait bound `&dyn HTML: HTML` is not satisfied
the trait `HTML` is not implemented for `&dyn HTML`
```

I somehow can't make the connection on where I have to define the `&dyn` part of the trait/trait impl!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dyn HTML` implements `HTML`, `&dyn HTML` doesn't. Either change `Body::new` to take `Vec<&C>` where `C: HTML`, or add a blanket implementation of `HTML` for references:

```rust
impl<T: HTML> HTML for &T {
    fn to_email_body(&self) {
        self.to_email_body()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The taking &C makes sense, allthough I start lifetime hell right there.... I don't quite get the "HTML for references". If I implement this for `&Dashboard`, nothing changes.

Comment: The important part is not to implement it for **a** reference, but for **every** reference. Note that the blanket implementation in my answer will automatically implement `HTML` for a reference to something that implements `HTML`.